Expo Go App stuck in splash screen on Android device
I'm just trying to open the Expo Go app to preview an app that I'm developing. It gets stuck in the splash screen and will take forever to open. And I'm talking about the Expo Go App splash screen, not my app splash screen. My device is a Samsung Galaxy Tab Active4 Pro.
I want to know what's going on and how can I solve this, this wasn't happening before and it's very annoying losing so much time. I've tried deleting the app cache memory, didn't work. I tried uninstalling and installing the app, but the problem persists even after installing it again.
